# Bootstrap works on local host but not on server

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, localhost, server

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
        <title>test</title>

        <!-- Bootstrap/css -->
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
        <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
        <link href="css/minestyle.less" rel="stylesheet">
        <!-- CUSTOM -->
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Orbitron' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poiret+One' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <!-- Hover effect -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style10.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style_common.css" />

        <link href="css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <!-- J.Q. *********** -->
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    </head>
```

I dont why but bootstrap work on localhost perfect (only IE make same result on localhost ) and when I upload it on server it seems like it ignore bootstrap ...

I try rewrite css/bootstrap.min.css to ../css/bootstrap.min.css but it doesnt work too ...

Does anyone know where is the problem ?

Comment: If you face bootstrap issue, then better try to use cdn for bootstrap.min from website

Comment: What server are you uploading to? IIS? Apache? Is it configured to serve CSS files?

Comment: apache / game-sector.eu / its weird something work and something not / i think the problem is with bootstrap .... interesting is that i have same issue with IE (11) on localhost

Answer (score 0):

Check your paths and folders. Maybie try (to find out if it's problem with paths) to put all files to single folder.

Also, you may want to use hosting dedicated for Bootstrap - http://www.bootstrap.hosting/.